# How to serve a R code that produces a Shiny app in your local shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following R code from (**[BatchQC package](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/BatchQC/inst/doc/BatchQCIntro.html)**)

```
 library(BatchQC)
    nbatch <- 3
    ncond <- 2
    npercond <- 10
    data.matrix <- rnaseq_sim(ngenes=50, nbatch=nbatch, ncond=ncond, npercond=
        npercond, basemean=10000, ggstep=50, bbstep=2000, ccstep=800, 
    basedisp=100, bdispstep=-10, swvar=1000, seed=1234)
batch <- rep(1:nbatch, each=ncond*npercond)
condition <- rep(rep(1:ncond, each=npercond), nbatch)
batchQC(data.matrix, batch=batch, condition=condition, 
        report_file="batchqc_report.html", report_dir=".", 
        report_option_binary="111111111",
        view_report=FALSE, interactive=TRUE, batchqc_output=TRUE)
```

When run in RStudio console, it produces this:

[image]

My question is how can I show that site through my local [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)

```
/srv/shiny-server/
```

Comment: You need to have a machine with shiny server installed on it, and move your shiny code into a folder under `/srv/shiny-server/` on that machine. 

I have instructions for that if you need http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/ (disclaimer: that's my own blog)

Comment: @DeanAttali I already have shiny server and have frequently made app and symlink to it. But this OP is different. See my answer to `lorenzov` below.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll write out an answer that might work

Comment: Just a thought here: The top of your browser screenshot shows a folder path. Is that function creating its own (temporary?) shiny app in that folder? If so, you might be able to grab it from there and make a copy to your `/srv/shiny-server` folder such that shiny starts to see it in the regular way.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean with local shiny server? when you run a preview from R that's local already.
if you have a full shiny server install on your machine, just create a folder in sample-apps and then point the browser to the shiny server (usually http://127.0.0.1:3838/sample-apps/youfolder/

Comment: the folder you mention should contain either "Rmd" files or `ui.R or server.R`.  But my code is a *function* wrapper to shiny app. Please try the command in my OP to see what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that BatchQC package, but assuming it's [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/mani2012/BatchQC), I looked at the `batchQC` function and saw this code:

```
    appDir <- system.file("shiny", "BatchQC", package = "BatchQC")
    if (appDir == "") {
        stop("Could not find shiny directory. Try re-installing BatchQC.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
```

So, I don't know if this will work or not (I wasn't able to install the package myself), but you can try to create an `app.R` file in your shiny server with the following lines:

```
appDir <- system.file("shiny", "BatchQC", package = "BatchQC")
shiny::runApp(appDir)
```

Can't guarantee it'll work, but try it out.